# "Одной или в совокупности нескольким другим организациям."

Tags: грамматика

Скажите, пожалуйста, во фразе "Одной или в совокупности нескольким другим организациям" относится ли слово *другим* к слову *одной*? Как относится и согласно какому правилу?

Answer (score 1):

Не относится.

Но нужен другой падеж и предлог: *одной или в совокупности (с чем?) **с несколькими другими организациями***.

Лучше заменить "*несколькими*" на "*некоторыми*".

"*В совокупности*" лучше, когда что-то рассматривается: *грамматика в совокупности с другими науками*.
Если это о действии (*действовать одной*), то лучше "***вместе*** с другими организациями".

Answer (score 0):

Вне контекста непонятно, зачем употреблено слово "другим": простое "одной" отвлечённо указывает на **единичность** как *количество*, альтернативой чему может служить **множественность** - "совокупность нескольких организаций" или "несколько организаций в совокупности", без противопоставления множественных организаций в качестве "других". Такое было бы возможным в случае альтернативы в виде "этой одной" организации и её же "в совокупности с несколькими другими". Из исходной же формулировки это не следует, хотя можно догадываться о таком желаемом смысле. Возможный контекст с сочетанием "одной", "в совокупности" и "других":

> Эта сумма денег была перечислена одной *этой* организации или
>   в совокупости ей и нескольким другим?